# IE 11 .hta file inserts double <br>

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, hta

I have a problem with `<br>` tag. I use the `<br>` tags to `clear:left;` my `float:` and to start a new line.
When I set `http-equiv`to:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=7">
```

I get single break line. But I want to force the content to be IE11 compatible so I can use `flex` in css. So I change the line to:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=11">
```

but this inserts an extra brake line to each `<br>` tag in code. In some sources this is known as a IE bug. It can be bypassed by inserting `line-height` parameter to `br{ ;}`style but the problem is that in .hta files this parameter is ignored. Is there any other way that I can force the tag to act normally in .hta?